# Callbacks for Request Module in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, request

I want to make a post request to an external API, then create an object of my own custom class based on the response from the post request. I'm using the request module to make the post request. I thought I would simply need to return the object from the callback function, but it looks like the function returns before the callback is completed, so a null object is always returned. How can I make the function wait for the callback function?

Function that makes the post request:

```
read(id: string) {
    request.post({
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        url: baseUrl + service,
        json: {
            "id": id
        }
    }, function(error: any, response: http.IncomingMessage, body: any) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var parsedJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
            /* tslint:disable:no-string-literal */
            if (parsedJson["status"] === "200") {
                var data = parsedJson["data"];
                return new Dummy.Dummy(id, data["dummy"]["value"], data["dummy2"]["value"], data["dummy3"]["value"]);
            }
            /* tslint:enable:no-string-literal */
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function returns `null` anyway because the condition:

```
if (parsedJson["status"] === "200")
```

never becomes true. So it just gets to the end of function and returns no value.

You must ispect this line of code behavior: `var parsedJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));`

It has `body` variable(that is string for sure) as argument to the `JSON.stringify` function. So stringifying string you will get "string of string object". Parsing it back with `JSON.parse` will return string object, that have no `status` property, so `parsedJson["status"]` will be null.

You must try `JSON.parse(body)` and double check `body` input for "status" property.

**Edit:**

It is important to tell that `return new Dummy.Dummy(...` returns the value from unnamed `function(error: any, response: http.IncomingMessage, body: any)`, **not** from the `read(id: string)`.

Since `request.post` uses async callback your unnamed function returns value to nowhere. You must use callback technique for example:

```
read(id: string, callback:(any) => any) {
    request.post({
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        url: baseUrl + service,
        json: {
            "id": id
        }
    }, function(error: any, response: http.IncomingMessage, body: any) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var parsedJson = JSON.parse(body);
            /* tslint:disable:no-string-literal */
            if (parsedJson["status"] === "200") {
                var data = parsedJson["data"];
                callback(Dummy.Dummy(id, data["dummy"]["value"], data["dummy2"]["value"], data["dummy3"]["value"]));
            }
            /* tslint:enable:no-string-literal */
        }
    });
}
```

Or you can use more advanced Promises techique or async flow control libraries.

Comment: I tried logging the new Dummy object inside the `if` check, and it correctly prints the Dummy object, so it is going inside the `if`. Also I tried parsing `body` without stringifying it at first (for the reasons you suggested), and it didn't work (I don't know why), but it worked after stringifying (still don't know why).

Comment: I checked the docs for `request.get`. Setting `json` parameter to request forces function to automaticaly parse `response` body as JSON, so you dont need `var parsedJson = JSON.parse(body);` code at all you can use `body["status"] === "200"` instead. Check my answer edit for some further explanations.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I'm still confused as to how to actually return the Dummy object to the function that calls the `read` function though. I made a callback function which simply takes the Dummy object as a param (like you indicated above), then returns the Dummy object. I then passed the function in as a param to the function that calls the `read` function. But the function still returns before finishing the callback...

Comment: You can't `return` a value from async code to sync. As i mean earlier you can solve this problem with callback. It works like this https://jsfiddle.net/t0dgedy0/